# How do I tell the Compute Engine gcutil-tool the location of a file when doing a push/pull?

Tags: google-compute-engine

gcutil does not understand when I use "d:/documents and settings/paul/desktop/somefile.txt"

I am using Cygwin terminal with Windows Xp.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin uses Unix-style paths, which do not have explicit drive letters.
Try `/cygdrive/d/Documents and Settings/...`

Answer (score 0):

With my Windows XP is so that D:\cygwin\home\exampleusername\examplefile.txt can be referenced as ~/examplefile.txt from the cygwin command line.

And I can get files from the Linux instance when I am at my local command prompt: I can "gutil ... pull ..." files from the instance and "gcutil ... push ..." files to instance.

Push or pull at the Linux instance command prompt does not work, I think this is a issue with my local firewall.